# Firestore Array contains ngIf

Tags: angular, firebase

I have the following data structure in firestore:

```
avisos: { //colection
  documentId1: { //documentId
    titulo: 'myTitle1'
    favoritos: ['three', 'two', 'one']
  },
  documentId2: {
    titulo: 'myTitle2'
    favoritos: ['two', 'five', 'four']
  },
  documentId3: {
    titulo: 'myTitle3'
    favoritos: ['eight', 'six', 'two']
  }
}
```

So I want to show an icon only if the `two` value is in the `favoritos` matrix, then I tried the following:

```
<div>
  <span>{{ aviso.categoria}}</span> //I have no problems with this
  <mat-icon *ngIf="aviso.favoritos.includes('two')">favorite_border</mat-icon>
</div>
```

but I get the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

I have also tried this, but I get the same error:

```
this.favoritos = this.afs.collection('avisos', ref => ref.where('favoritos', 'array-contains', 'two') ).valueChanges();
```

Any idea how I can address this issue?

Comment: Have you made index in firestore of favoritos? You should try with index.

Comment: What do you get if you console.log(aviso)? basically that error means favoritos is undefined

Comment: If I print `console.log (this.aviso);` I get the data of each document of the entire collection, in any case how can I avoid undefined?

Comment: @PacoZevallos so when you log you are getting `{ //colection
  documentId1: { //documentId
    titulo: 'myTitle1'
    favoritos: ['three', 'two', 'one']
  },
  documentId2: {
    titulo: 'myTitle2'
    favoritos: ['two', 'five', 'four']
  },
  documentId3: {
    titulo: 'myTitle3'
    favoritos: ['eight', 'six', 'two']
  }
}` right?

Comment: That's right, that's what the console shows. The data is loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check if `avisos` is not undefined in your component.If so Then you can't access `aviso.favoritos` directly you have to change it to `aviso.documentId1.favoritos` same thing for `documentId2,documentId3` as well.Also use Safe navigation oprator`?` to avoid errors when data is loading so your code should look like

```
<mat-icon *ngIf="aviso?.documentId1?.favoritos?.includes('two') || aviso?.documentId2?.favoritos?.includes('two') || aviso?.documentId3?.favoritos?.includes('two')">favorite_border</mat-icon>
```

Comment: @KruPa op doesn't mention that in requirement in that case he can use `Object.keys` to loop over each key

Comment: Excellent, this answer helped a lot, I had to use the operator `?` That was it, in the end it went like this: `*ngIf ="aviso?.favoritos?.includes('two')"`

Comment: @PacoZevallos i am not sure how you are able to access `aviso?.favoritos` when your data looks like `aviso:{document1:{favoritos:[]}}....` bcs in that case `aviso?.favoritos` whould always be null